# How to install wpengine hosted multisite locally

Tags: multisite, migration, local-installation

Does anyone have any insight into how to install a copy of a wpengine hosted site locally? You can assume Wordpress migration knowledge i.e. I have a copy of the files and have imported the  DB locally.

I am getting 'Error establishing a database connection' even though I am 100% sure that I have edited the wp-config DB connection details correctly. This is a **multisite** install.

**UPDATE**

From wpengine : "You will need to remove our platform specific files found in the mu-plugins folder and the object-cache.php found in the wp-content folder...Outside of changing all of the subsite urls and the primary domain, there shouldn't be anything specific to our platform."

Comment: Even though you think you have, you probably haven't. Did you copy WPEs config file ad-hoc and modify those details or did you start from a fresh install/config file? Paste your config file contents (blank out sensitive details). WPEs config files are tailored to their environment.

Comment: I copied their file and edited that. I am currently AFK so can't upload config file til later.

Comment: @userabuser see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Search-Replace-DB from https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB to replace domain urls for the site I needed to develop.

I also had trouble with the WP Sharely plugin which was enabled sitewide - it was looking for an activation file on a NAS box in the cloud somewhere. Once I disabled sitewide plugins manually in the DB, I was able to log in and view the site.

As advised by wpengine, I removed their platform specific code from the mu-plugins folder and also the object-cache.php from /wp-content

I have deleted my wp-config from above for security.

Comment: The details don't seem to have any confidential information, and they are [available in the post history](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/118901/revisions) anyway. If it was the case, you should [notify a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117) asking for removal of the revision history. But IMO you should instead republish the info, as it has some nice details about WPE config and `wp-config.php` in general.